# Passing a props component through a Stack Navigator (React Navigation v5)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am working on an expo react native application with react-navigation v5.
I have created 2 navigators : one StackNavigator if the user is not signed in, and one bottomTabNavigator if he is. In the first stackNavigator, I have a screen Login which takes one prop onAuthSucces used in a TouchableOpacity like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.signIn}>
   <Text style={{ color: "dimgray", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
      Se connecter
   </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The signIn function is written like this :

```
signIn = () => {
    const user = authenticationService.authenticate(
      this.state.login,
      this.state.password
    );
    if (user !== null) {
      this.props.onAuthSuccess(user);
    } else
      Alert.alert(
        "Erreur de connexion",
        "Votre identifiant et/ou votre mot de passe sont incorrects. Réessayez."
      );
  };
```

with a props onAuthSuccess of type : `onAuthSuccess: (loggedUser: User) => void;`

I tried to create a StackNavigator which can take parameters, and will affect these to the Login props, with :

```
const LoginPageStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
export const LoginStackScreen = (onAuthSuccess: any) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <LoginPageStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <LoginPageStack.Screen name="Login">
          {(props) => <Login {...props} onAuthSuccess={onAuthSuccess} />}
        </LoginPageStack.Screen>
        <LoginPageStack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
      </LoginPageStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Finally, in App.tsx I use these different pages this like :

```
interface AppState {
  currentUser: User | null;
  isConnected: boolean;
}

export default class App extends Component<AppState> {
  state: AppState = {
    currentUser: null,
    isConnected: false,
  };

  updateCurrentUser = (loggedUser: User) => {
    this.setState({ currentUser: loggedUser });
    this.setState({ isConnected: true });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isConnected) return <MainTabNavigator />;
    else {
      return (
        <LoginStackScreen onAuthSuccess={this.updateCurrentUser} />
      );
   }
}
```

But when I try to connect me with a login and a password that are stocked in the database, Expo Go tells me : "TypeError: _this.props.onAuthSuccess is not a function. (In '_this.props.onAuthSuccess(user)', '_this.props.onAuthSuccess' is an instance of Object)"

Do you have any idea from where the problem can come ? I don't understand.

Thank you !

Comment: Unfortunately you can't actually do this. It's kind of frustrating that the dev team doesn't make it crystal clear that the components can't really be used like you'd expect. If you want to pass values down, you'll need to use React's Context system - or at least that's what they recommend.